# Как исправить ошибку с mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli

Всем привет! Я новичок в php. Мне почему-то выдаёт такие ошибки

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in D:\openserver\OpenServer\domains\localhost\inc\config.php on line 5

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in D:\openserver\OpenServer\domains\localhost\inc\config.php on line 6

```
<?php 
require 'db.php';
$sql_select1 = "SELECT * FROM `config";
$result1 = mysqli_query($sql_select1);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
$sname = $row['sname'];
?>
```

Comment: Руководство открывал? https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-parameters Читал?

Comment: Зачем вы мне на вопрос вопросом отвечаете?

Comment: Я тебе подсказываю, что делать.

Comment: "expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given" -- написано же, предельно ясно.

Answer (score 0):

Первым параметром функции `mysqli_query` должно быть подключение к базе.
Например:

```
$link = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

$sql_select1 = "SELECT * FROM `config";
$result1 = mysqli_query($link, $sql_select1);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
$sname = $row['sname'];
```